# Should I change text-domain of TGM library inside theme?

Tags: theme-development, translation, localization, textdomain

I created a theme and I want to publish it in wordpress.org. I used TGM library to check to require plugins. but the Theme-check get bellow warning:

> Warning: More than one text-domain is being used in this theme. This
>   means the theme will not be compatible with WordPress.org language
>   packs.

Should I change text-domain of TGM library? Or like the Envato, it's not necessary to change text-domain of TGM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Themes should always have only one textdomain - most of the localization tools base on that assumption, so if you put multiple textdomains in the same theme, you make localizing it much harder.

As for wordpress.org... It is clearly stated that:

> Themes that are hosted on WordPress.org the text domain must match the
>   slug of your theme URL (wordpress.org/themes/). This is needed
>   so that the translations from translate.wordpress.org work correctly.
>
> The text domain name must use dashes and not underscores and be
>   lowercase. For example, if the theme’s name My Theme is defined in the
>   style.css or it is contained in a folder called my-theme the text
>   domain should be my-theme.
>
> The text domain is used in three different places:
>
> In the style.css theme header As an argument in the localization
>   functions As an argument when loading the translations using
>   load_theme_textdomain() or  load_child_theme_textdomain() style.css
>   theme header #style.css theme header The text domain is added to the
>   style.css header so that the theme meta-data like the description can
>   be translated even when the theme is not enabled. The text domain
>   should be same as the one used when loading the text domain.
>
> Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/#text-domain